# In Azure Logic App, how do I pass parameters in a http request?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to download a file from a website that requires me to pass parameters while making the HTTP request. The request is as follows

```
https:/wwww.xxx.com/download/exportdata.go?pid=3276439&startdate=2015-01-01&enddate=2015-01-02
```

Though when I hard code the request it works perfectly, but now that I want to download this file on a schedule, i need to be able to change the date for the startdate and enddate parameters?

I was trying to explore the expressions of utcnow and adddays, but not much success? What do i need to do to pass these parameters?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: So the error i get is as follows {"code":"BadRequest","message":"Http request failed: the timeout was reached."}

Comment: So the error i get is as follows  {"code":"BadRequest","message":"Http request failed: the timeout was reached."}.  I directly entered utc now in the link  https:/wwww.xxx.com/download/exportdata.go?pid=3276439&startdate=2015-01-01&receivedend=@{utcnow()} " but utcnow format is not something that the link expects

Comment: the link shows ends with 2015-05-29T06:18:21.9352385Z. Is there a way to reformat the utcnow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass arguments you can use the "@{}" syntax, and use the builtin functions such as "utcnow, adddays, concat, base64, length, contains, int, string, float, addhours, rand, toLower, toUpper, etc".

To add formatting to the date returned when using the @utcnow() function you can pass an optional argument to the call to use it as the formatting argument, something like:

```
http://api.example.org/weather?lat=35&lon=139&time=@{utcnow('yyyy-MM-dd')}
```

For more information on what that formatting string can look like you can use "C#" formatting as detailed in the following page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings